# Mockito is not mocking the method

Tags: java, spring, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am trying to write a test case for a method, but that method is not getting mocked I guess.

Here is the method whose response is returning null:

```
      response = httpClient.makeRequest(HttpMethod.POST, params.getUrl(), request, headers, null, param1.getRequest().getId(),
          param1, false);
```

The actual method:

```
  public HttpResponse makeRequest(String method, String url, String param, Header[] headers, String serviceName, String requestId,
      className param1, Boolean useProxy) throws SystemException {
....
....
....
return httpResponse;
}
```

This is the mocking code of the respected method:

```
Mockito.when(httpClient.makeRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(response);
```

The exception that I am getting:

```
com.morfeus.workflow.exception.WorkflowException: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.morfeus.workflow.processor.WebhookProcessor.process(WebhookProcessor.java:164)
    at com.morfeus.workflow.processor.script.WebhookScriptProcessorTest.process(WebhookScriptProcessorTest.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.morfeus.workflow.processor.WebhookProcessor.process(WebhookProcessor.java:151)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: please post all code and exception eraised

Comment: "*`..., Mockito.any(), ...`*" - Do not use untyped matchers. Rather type it: `Mockito.any(YourClassHere.class)`.

Comment: Not working in that case as well.

Comment: I know I have to learn more, but it was urgent that's why I asked.
Anyways thank you. :)

Comment: I would like to add a suggestion for your tests, as I see this a lot and I think it makes the tests weak.  Try to avoid using the any matchers.  You should know the arguments that you expect to be passed to the method, so use matchers that will capture this, e.g. eq().  The entire reason your mock isn't behaving as you expect is because it's not matching the arguments.  Debug your test, break on the line of the method call, inspect your arguments and find the ones that don't match up.  As pointed out, you can't use an any matcher on null.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `null` but expecting `anyString()`.

From [docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyString()),

> Since Mockito 2.1.0, only allow non-null String. As this is a nullable reference, the suggested API to match null wrapper would be isNull(). We felt this change would make tests harness much safer that it was with Mockito 1.x.

Use [`isNull`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isNull()) instead.

Modify it to,

```
Mockito.when(httpClient.makeRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.isNull(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(response);
```

or don't pass `null`.

Comment: What did you modify it into? Can you post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?